# Issue with unix_error function in c

Tags: c, linux, unix, error-handling

So I am having trouble with the unix_error function, I believe that I am not including a specific file but I can't seem to find what file that I need to include on the internet. Any tips?

EDIT: I write something like this..

```
while((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0){
        printf("SERVER: Handler reaped child %d\n", (int) pid);
        child_count--;
    }
    if(errno != ECHILD){
        unix_error("waitpid error");
    }
    sleep(2);
    return;
```

I get errors when trying to compile for the unix_error

Comment: Additional details, please

Comment: @Louis just added the edits.

Comment: you can use perror instead of unix_error.unix_error is some sort of warppaer function written by someone and it is not the standard.

Comment: Probably you might be compiling some book sample source code.

Comment: Presumably, in addition to perror, unix_error probably calls exit(errno).

Comment: It is probably from the book http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/. It is defined here: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ics2/code/src/csapp.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard function `unix_error()`.

For many purposes, you could use this code.

#### unixerr.h

```
#ifndef UNIXERR_H_INCLUDED
#define UNIXERR_H_INCLUDED

extern void unix_error(const char *msg);

#endif /* UNIXERR_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### unixerr.c

```
#include "unixerr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void unix_error(const char *msg)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s (%d: %s)\n", msg, errnum, strerror(errnum));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

There are many improvements that could be made. A primary one would be adding the program name to the start of the output.  Another would be making the function support a variable length argument list like `printf()` does. Some people don't like printing the error number; I prefer it.